# Scrapping en Facebook

Tags: python, scraping, facebook

buen dia, mi maestro de Inteligen Artificial nos dio como "mini-proyecto" sacar 80 muestras de amigos y obtener quien es hombre y quien es mujer en base a su link de perfil.
Vi que una forma de hacerlo es con Web-scrapping pero no me ha quedado muy claro si esto es legal o tendria problemas con facebook por obtener esos datos, vi el modulo facebook-scrapper pero no se si sea buena idea usarlo. Existe otro acecamiento a este problema?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Aunque no estás planteando un problema como tal intentaré darte alguna idea para que intentes cosas. En principio si son datos públicos no debería ser considerado ilegal acceder a ellos. Otro tema sería el qué hagas con esos datos. De cualquier manera aparte de hacerlo por scraping (que te va a dar dolores de cabeza en cuanto hagas demasiadas peticiones) tienes disponible la Graph API de facebook.

Comment: Podrías realizar un prototipo con el módulo faker de python. Aquí un enlace: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.profile.html